# python subprocess not executed --> DNS error

Tags: python, subprocess

We use python subprocess to launch an .exe file. That program is launched in a folder and gives and image.
The programs were used for months and the still work in my account. However, when using a colleague's account, we get the following error.

*C:\WINDOWS\system32>spyder
[13552:860:0703/181421.396:ERROR:dns_config_service_win.cc(755)] DNS config watch failed.*

We tried different machines and the problem persists with her.
We also tried to launch the python program from the command window without spyder, but it did not solve it.

snipped of the software. As you can see, subprocess executes a string in the folder defined.

```
def executeCmd(self,string):
    p = subprocess.Popen(string,cwd=self.folder,shell=False)
    p.wait()
```

Comment: "We also tried to launch the program from the command window, but it did not solve it." -- so why do you think the problem is with python and subprocess, if the program you're trying to launch doesn't work by itself? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I did not phrase it correctly, we tried to launch the python program from the command window instead of through Spyder. as we are using anaconda distribution.

Comment: Ah, okay. Can you try to run the program directly, not through Python? The error message doesn't look like it has anything to do with Python, to be honest.

Comment: It was a problem of rights to access to a folder in our servers. But it is just a guess. Thanks.